# Get ng-model from a input inside directive and put it in an attribute of directive

Tags: angularjs

I have "nibTextbox" directive with an input inside it,input has a ng-model,I want that ng-model value always available in "value" attribute of directive.(I don't wanna use replace)

```
    angular.module('nib', [])
    .directive('nibTextbox', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                id: '@',
                title: '@',
            },
            compile: function (element, attributes) {

                var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {

                }
                return linkFunction;
            },
            controller: ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

            }],
            template: '<div value="{{nibTextBoxValue}}"><img src="" alt=""/><label>{{title}}</label><input id="{{id}}_txt" type="text" ng-model="nibTextBoxValue"></input></div>'
        };
    });


<nib-textbox id="ngArmin1" title="ngArmin1Title" value="{{nibTextBoxValue}}"></nib-textbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is not valid for a `<div>` element. So let's change it to `data-div`.
This is how it will look more or less (I usually work with typescript but I'll use plain javascript to pass the idea):

```
 angular.module('nib', [])
    .directive('nibTextbox', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                id: '@',
                title: '@',
            },
            compile: function (element, attributes) {

                var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {

                }
                return linkFunction;
            },
             // Injected $element for manipulating attributes                
             controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$element', function ($scope, $http, $element) {


              $scope.$watch("nibTextBoxValue", function(newValue) {
              $element.attr("data-value", newValue);
          });
       }],
            templateUrl: 'template.html' // Extracting the template to a file
        };
    });
```

The directive template (template.html):

```
<div>
  <img src="" alt=""/><label>{{title}}</label>
  <input id="{{id}}_txt" type="text" ng-model="nibTextBoxValue"></input>
  </div>
```

In addition, remove the `value` attribute from your directive:

`<nib-textbox id="ngArmin1" title="ngArmin1Title"></nib-textbox>`

Comment: thanks man,your a good boy :D,thanks a lot, I'd change your answer a little and it worked,the idea was using $watch.(no need to use data-value,only value)

Answer (score 0):

the answer:use $watch
change controller definition to this:

```
controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$element', function ($scope, $http, $element) {
                    $scope.$watch("nibTextBoxValue", function (nv) {
                        $element.attr("value", nv);
                    });
                }]
```